# how to change the encoding of the java compilation error message?

Tags: java

for example,I tried to compile a java file which can not pass the compilation in a cmd line.
the java code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello World")
    }
}
```

cmd line:
javac HelloWorld.java

and the compilation error message will be showed in the cmd window.
[image: the error message]

its encoding  is GBK,but the cmd program's encoding is utf-8.
How can I change the encoding of the java compilation error message?(I'm using windows 10 and jdk8)

Comment: Please check other questions like https://superuser.com/questions/346498/how-do-i-change-my-cmd-exe-to-english and https://superuser.com/questions/1309399/change-display-language-in-windows-10-with-cmd-or-powershell-commands

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the default codepage on Windows when you use Terminal.

Use the `chcp` command at the CMD and PowerShell prompt to list the current code page.

On this page: ["Code Page Identifiers - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) you will find a list of all Windows code pages. Last on the list is utf-8.

In the Windows 10 version (most current in January 2022) we can configure Regional Settings. Chose the Unicode utf-8 Check-box on Regional Settings of Settings/Regional.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOElo.png